# Jenkins doesn't find fonts for phpDocumentor

Tags: jenkins, javadoc, fonts

I have a problem with Jenkins and phpDocumentor. After a successful build, I want to open the documentation. Everything works fine except the icons, which are displayed as squares. A short look in the developer tools shows this error message:

Request:

> GET **/job/PROJECTNAME/javadoc/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.2.1** HTTP/1.1
>   Host: URLTOJENKINS
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
>   Accept: */*
>   Referer: http://URLTOJENKINS.com/job/PROJECTNAME/javadoc/namespaces/SOMEPAGE.html
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Response:

> HTTP/1.1 **404 Not Found**
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
>   Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
>   Content-Length: 1410
>   Server: Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)